# Missing Section: Displacement and Bumps

Tags: displacement

I'm following a tutorial on youtube and one step my version of blender 2.8.2 and his 2.8 don't seem to match up.

This is in the shading section and here's what I have for nodes

[image]
[image]

and the section I expect to find the displacement option in settings at the right section

[image]

not there but on the tutorial it's there

[image]

Comment: Hey :). You need to change your render engine to Cycles. You're currently using Eevee, which doesn't support displacement.